# Pyspark : Check if a column contain values from another

Tags: pyspark, dataset, compare

I have a dataset like this :

| Trigger A | Trigger B | Trigger C | Trigger D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | null | null | null |
| null | null | b | null |
| null | c | null | null |

And another dataset like this

| header | issue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | x |
| 4 | e |

I want to create a new column "check" that return 1 if issue is in Trigger A, B, c or D and 0 if not

In this example this is the result :

| header | issue | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | x | 0 |
| 4 | e | 0 |

Thanks !

Comment: can there be 2 triggers in a single row?

Comment: Hi, no there is only 1 trigger (or 0) i a single row

Answer (score 0):

given you mention that each row can have at most 1 trigger value, you can transform the first dataframe to a single column and then join with the second dataframe.

here's an example

```py
trigger_issue_sdf = data1_sdf.select(
    func.coalesce(*data1_sdf.columns).alias("issue"), func.lit(1).alias("check")
).dropDuplicates()

data2_sdf.join(trigger_issue_sdf, ["issue"], "left").fillna(0, subset=["check"]).show()


# +-----+------+-----+
# |issue|header|check|
# +-----+------+-----+
# |    b|     2|    1|
# |    a|     1|    1|
# |    x|     3|    0|
# |    e|     4|    0|
# +-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Example tables:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


triggers = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    data=[("a", None, None, None), (None, None, "b", None), (None, "c", None, None)],
    schema=T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("A", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("B", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("C", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("D", T.StringType()),
        ]
    ),
)
triggers.show()

issues = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    data=[("1", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "x"), ("4", "e")],
    schema=T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("header", T.StringType()),
            T.StructField("issue", T.StringType()),
        ]
    ),
)
issues.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   C|   D|
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|null|null|null|
|null|null|   b|null|
|null|   c|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+

+------+-----+
|header|issue|
+------+-----+
|     1|    a|
|     2|    b|
|     3|    x|
|     4|    e|
+------+-----+
```

First, union issue values from triggers table:

```py
distinct_trigger_issues = (
    (
        triggers.select("A")
        .unionAll(triggers.select("B"))
        .unionAll(triggers.select("C"))
        .unionAll(triggers.select("D"))
        .distinct()
    )
    .withColumnRenamed("A", "issue")
    .withColumn("check", F.lit(1))
)
distinct_trigger_issues.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
|issue|check|
+-----+-----+
| null|    1|
|    c|    1|
|    b|    1|
|    a|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Next, left-join `issues` table with `distinct_trigger_issues`. In the result table, `check` column value equals 1, when an issue is in `distinct_trigger_issues`, otherwise `null`. Last, substitute nulls with 0.

```py
issues_checked = issues.join(distinct_trigger_issues, how="left", on=["issue"]).fillna(
    value=0, subset=["check"]
)
issues_checked.show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+-----+
|issue|header|check|
+-----+------+-----+
|    x|     3|    0|
|    e|     4|    0|
|    b|     2|    1|
|    a|     1|    1|
+-----+------+-----+
```